# Shared printing problems Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a printer (HP laserjet 4100) connected to one computer running windows 7 through USB (to be precise using parallel to USB cable). I have shared this printer so that other users (running windows 7) on the network can print to the same printer.

They can print a number of pages then the printing stops completely for the shared users until the computer which is directly connected to the printer is restarted then the printer starts printing the old jobs.

I have tried the home group kind of sharing and direct kind of sharing an getting the same result.

What could be the problem because I had the same setup with XP and never had a proble until the upgrade

Comment: Check out if the spooler is having an issue, I have seen UAC cause printing issues in the past. Next time it happens go to services.msc and restart the print spooler. If it starts working something is interfering with the spooler service and we can trouble shoot from there.